# Subscribe a user to Campaign Monitor during checkout in craft commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I found [this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20697/is-it-possible-to-subscribe-a-user-to-mailchimp-during-checkout-in-craft-commerc) for Mailchimp. Is there somewhere also a [plugin solution](https://github.com/aelvan/mailchimp-subscribe-craft) for Campaign Monitor? I can't find anything via google.

Answer (score 1):

I have a form on my checkout receipt page for Campaign Monitor and looking in my composer.json I can see:
`clearbold/craft-campaignmonitor-lists`